# Magento 1.7 - Two magento in one server are effecting each other

Tags: linux, magento, magento-1.7

I have 2 magento files in one server(linux) , one is live and other one is for testing. Both have different url. The testing magento is just setup by coping the live files and database. But I found out the testing magento will effect the live magento (for example I plugin the new template into testing magento , the live magento css and desgin will run also). Any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have updated the URL in all of the config files AND the database.  The easiest way to do this is to dump the database of the new site, find and replace the url of the original install with the new one then re-import it.

If you've been consistent with not hard coding links or images in CMS pages then the URL should only appear in these places:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/update_site_url_in_core_config_data

Answer (score -1):

You should use one magento on one server. Just create multiple stores in one. and redirect each store you what you want. www.example.com -> store 1; www.example1.com -> store 2 and so on. Magento works faster if you do that way. i have experience with multiple magento on one server. after more people start to use your store then server will start to lag or magento will start to work a lot slower.

Comment: This definitely wouldn't be ideal if you had several clients sharing a server.  With that said, I wouldn't ever recommend that given how heavy magento is.

Comment: Hi, the second magento is used on testing purpose, so we needed two magento instead of multiple store.

Answer (score -1):

this is happening because you have copied the database and files due to which in local.xml and in database table core_config there is information related to your live files, instead you should setup again the TESTING copy, just follow this steps.

1. take the backup of file local.xml from location /app/etc and after backup delete this file
2. Now after doing that just access the testing domain, now your setup for testing copy will start.

this will create new configuration information for testing copy